# Not able to SELECT a DB view

Tags: oracle11g

In Oracle, i have below scenario but facing authorization issue.

Schema A:
Has 3 tables: TA1, TA2, TA3

Schema B:
Has DB View 'VB' on joining tables TA1, TA2 and TA3

User C:
Has SELECT grant on VB

Problem:
SELECT grant is provided to C on view 'VB' but it is not accessible from 'C'.
I have also tried granting SELECT access on TA1, TA2 and TA3 to C but it did not work.

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grant using the `WITH GRANT` option

As `schema_a`, grant access to underlying tables with the option to give that grant to another schema

```
GRANT select ON ta1 TO schema_b WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT select ON ta2 TO schema_b WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT select ON ta3 TO schema_b WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

As `schema_b`, you can now grant select on the view using those tables to `schema_c`

```
GRANT select ON vb TO schema_c;
```

As `schema_c` you can select from the vb but not the underlying tables directly.

```
SELECT * from schema_b.vb;
```

No need to grant select on the tables directly to `schema_c`